# print value of char array which is loaded with void pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, copy, command-line-arguments, c-strings

I have below code where I am passing address of array of charectors to function "GetStr". GetStr function prototype is fixed.

Here in below code I am passing command line argument where string to function "GetStr" and update the value in the address of variable "str".

**PRoblem**:
At Print 1, I am getting the value what I passed from command line arguments. A Print 2 in main function, I am unable to print or get the value back. Could you please let me know how to print the value at "Print 2" statement

```
int GetStr(void *RetVal, int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc != 0){

        if(argv != NULL && argv[1] != '\0'){
            RetVal = argv[1];
        }
        else{
            RetVal = '\0';
        }
        cout<< " RetVal: " << (char *)RetVal <<endl; ->>>  PRINT 1
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Driver:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char str[8];

    GetStr(str,argc,argv);

    cout<<"HH: "<<((char *)(str))<<endl;  ->>>  PRINT 2 
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to the dangers of `void*`. A `void *` can eat pretty much anything with little complaint. In `RetVal = argv[1];` `RetVal is pointed at a `char *`, but `RetVal = '\0';` points it at a `char`. This SHOULD result in a compiler error, but some compilers let it by for legacy reasons. This will blow the program up in horrible horrible ways later if you don't know they have to be untangled. For example, `cout<< " RetVal: " << (char *)RetVal <<endl;` will treat that null character as a a pointer and print it, effectively dereferencing a null pointer. Boom.

Comment: General rule of thumb: Don't use a `void*` unless forced to. C++ has many, many ways to avoid them.

Comment: So the error isn't in the printing (though you could remove the cast), the error is in the way you fail to copy the string in the `GetStr` function. As is common with newbies you are failing to see the difference between changing a pointer and changing what the pointer is pointing at. If you are going to use pointers it's vital to understand the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `strcpy()` to copy a string. You're just assigning the address of `argv[1]` to the local variable `RetVal`, which has no effect on the array in the caller.

You should also check `argc` to determine if `argv[1]` has been supplied.

```
int GetStr(void *RetVal, int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc != 0){

        if(argv != NULL && argc >= 2){
            strcpy((char*)RetVal, argv[1]); // copy first argument
        }
        else{
            *(char*)RetVal = '\0'; // Set to empty string
        }
        cout<< " RetVal: " << (char *)RetVal <<endl; ->>>  PRINT 1
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that it's necessary to cast `RetVal` before indirecting through it in the assignment, because you can't dereference a `void` pointer.

Comment: Commenting to draw attention to the extra cast and dereference used at `*(char*)RetVal = '\0';` This is the magic sauce that allows the `void*` to be treated as a `char *` and ultimately as a `char`  that can be assigned to.

Comment: @Barmar, it works. I havedone small edit in strcpy in your code, I added (char*) just before RetVal.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice that this was C++. In C the cast is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `RetVal` is a local variable of the function `GetStr`. Changes of it do not influence on the original argument passed to the function. Moreover as the original argument is an array then arrays do not have the assignment operator. You have to copy characters pointed to by `argv[1]` to the passed array.

So in any case this statement

```
RetVal = argv[1];
```

and this

```
RetVal = '\0';
```

have no effect relative to the passed array. And it is unclear what you are trying to do in the second statement above. Either you want to set the pointer to NULL. Or you want to set the first pointed byte to the terminating zero character that is invalid because the pointer is not dereferenced and moreover has the type `void *`.

Also it seems that instead of this expression in the if statement

```
argv[1] != '\0'
```

you mean either

```
argv[1][0] != '\0'
```

or

```
argv[1] != nullptr
```

In any case these two if statements

```
if(argc != 0){

    if(argv != NULL && argv[1] != '\0'){
```

can be substituted for one if statement as

```
if ( not ( argc < 2 ) )
```

The function can look at least the following way

```
int GetStr( void *RetVal, int argc, char **argv )
{
    int error = argc < 2 ? -1 : 0;

    if ( not error )
    {
        strcpy( RetVal, argv[1] );
    }

    return error;
}
```

The function should not output anything except for the debug purpose. It is the caller of the function will decide whether to output a message if any.

Pay attention to that the function is unsafe because the passed array can be less than it is required to copy the string pointed to by `argv[1]`.